# Register window in blank on immunity debugger

Tags: debugging, ftp, exploit

Everytime when I send a buffer 1000 bytes long to the freefloat ftp server in the MKD command , it crashes. I am trying to develop an exploit for it so I attached the immunity debugger to the freefloat ftp server process but when I send the buffer to the ftp server and I press play in the immunity debugger , the register window get in blank , I have been so long trying to fix this, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press Alt + C to get it back. It's a bug in immunity where the registers window disappears when you hit play.

To get it back, you need to reset the CPU view. You can do this by going to View -> CPU. Or with the hotkeys "Alt + C"

Little late, but hope it helps.